# Play Java Forms doesn't check constraints recursively

Tags: java, json, recursion, playframework-2.0

I'm building an applicaiton using Play framework 2.3 in Java.

I have POST requests with a JSON body. So, for retreiving data, I'm using Form with multiple level of imbrication to respect the JSON model. It works very well but I recently view that it doesn't check the constraints (like Constraints.Required). I don't actualy know if it was always having this behavior or if it's only form my last test but I can't let it as it is.

So does any one know if it's possible to recursively check constraints ?

You have the exemple of the case that is not working here :

```
public class PairRequest
{
    @Constraints.Required
    public String epc;

    @Constraints.Required
    public RequestProduct product;
}


public class RequestProduct
{
    //Product data
    @Constraints.Required
    public String productCode;

    @Constraints.Required
    public Brand brand;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String furniture;
}
```

Here if the field 'furniture' is not present, hasError() function return false.

```
import static play.data.Form.form;

public static Result pair(String tokenString)
{
    try
    {
        Token token = Token.getToken(tokenString);
        PairingCommit commit = PairingCommitService.getCommit(token.user);
        Form<PairRequest> form = form(PairRequest.class).bindFromRequest();

        if(form.hasErrors())//check out for form errors
            throw Error.BAD_REQUEST(form.errors());

        CommitItemService.create(form.get(), commit);

        return ok(toJson(Response.OK));
    }
    catch(Error error){ return ok(toJson(error)); }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but would you mark fields as private and provide valid java beans getters and setters?

Comment: Play generate getters and setters for me when a field is public. And I'm not sure that Form and Ebean are linked

Comment: Would you include to the question how you bind forms, please?

Comment: And what `form()` method does?

Comment: It's a static import of `play.data.Form.form()`

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what the problem is. I have a very similar form (Play 2.4) with inner forms and validation works well. The only difference are private fields and explicit getters/setters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81989/discussion-between-emrys-myrooin-and-mon-calamari).

Comment: I will try to pass fileds to private

Comment: It haven't change every thing :-( But I notice that Ebean raise a non blocking OutOfBoundException at the compilation time... But the application is compiled and the return code is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `@Valid` Annotation.

Comment: I have finaly found out in other posted question but thank you ;-)